# How do i compare the sum of two fields to another field on the same model in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here is my model

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    """
    Keep track of the monetary values of a company's wallet
    """
    serializer_class = WalletSocketSerializer

    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, verbose_name=_('company'))
    packaged_credits = models.BigIntegerField(_('packaged credits'), default=0)
    purchased_credits = models.BigIntegerField(_('purchased credits'), default=0)
    low_credits_threshold = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Now i would like to send an alert if the total credits are less than the threshold, this would be the equivalent of getting all low wallets in this SQL

`select * from wallets_wallet where (packaged_credits + purchased_credits) < low_credits_threshold;`

I want to know how to execute that in django, right now i have tried the following, it works, but i think it should be done in a more Django way:

```
low_wallets = []
        for wallet in Wallet.objects.all():
            if wallet.packaged_credits + wallet.purchased_credits < wallet.low_credits_threshold:
                low_wallets.append(wallet)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F

low_wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(
    low_credits_threshold__gt=F('packaged_credits')+F('purchased_credits')
)
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, i will go with Dr Manhattan's answer because it looks more    elegant

Comment: mm elegant but i see the django docs say to use it as a last resort, so your answer goes here

Answer (score 1):

Wallet.objects.extra(where=["packaged_credits + purchased_credits < low_credits_threshold"])

Comment: As [the docs note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra), `extra` is discouraged; this can be achieved using F functions, as Vladimir shows.